# Stripe: How to get platform's stripe account id?

Tags: stripe-payments

I was following these docs to debit connected stripe account.

https://stripe.com/docs/connect/account-debits

For creating transfer we need "PLATFORM_STRIPE_ACCOUNT_ID".

```py
stripe.Transfer.create
(
  amount=1500,
  currency="usd",
  destination="{{PLATFORM_STRIPE_ACCOUNT_ID}}",
  stripe_account='{{CONNECTED_ACCOUNT_ID}}',
)
```

The docs say you can use account api to retrieve your account id.

```py
stripe.Account.retrieve('{{CONNECTED_ACCOUNT_ID}}')
```

But how would retrieving connected_account give my / platforms account id?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are looking for you own account ID (`acct_xxx`), you can find it at the top of this dashboard page: https://dashboard.stripe.com/settings/account.